# L_2-Betti numbers of random groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Are there any results in calculating $l_2$-Betti numbers of random groups in the Gromov density model?

I can deduce myself a few facts:

1. If a group has Property (T) then the first $l_2$-Betti number is 0. Therefore, for densities $> \frac{1}{3}$ with overwhelimng probability a random group has $\beta_1^{(2)} = 0$.
2. In the triangular random group model (Zuk's model) for densities $< \frac{1}{3}$ a random group is w.o.p. free so it has w.o.p. non zero $\beta_1^{(2)}$.

There are many theorems about $l_2$-Betti numbers, so maybe You will see some facts that can be applied to calculate or estimate $l_2$-Betti numbers of random groups?